# Why is the HTML after a DOM manipulation not updated within Firebug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug

I have updated the HTML of a `<div>` using `jQuery.ajax()`.

It is working fine, but after that when I inspect the `<div>` in Firebug the HTML is not updated.

I mean to say that this `jQuery.ajax()` call is working fine when I see it as a user, but when I see the HTML using Firebug it is not updated.

Comment: Which version of FF and FireBug are you using? That might help, I guess. Usually it updates automatically. You just have to "Inspect" the element as Mark said - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078755/jquery-ajax-problem/1078763#1078763

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug in an old version of Firebug. Newer versions should not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing the Web Developer extension and using the View Generated Source option from the View Source menu.  The regular View Source will only show you the original HTML, not any updates made using javascript/ajax.

Comment: View Generated Source will show you the updates made dynamically using javascript, including ajax.